# KotlinJS: When would I use Kotlin dynamic type

Tags: javascript, kotlin

This is related to [KotlinJS](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/js-overview.html) (transpiling Kotlin to JavaScript):

Kotlin has a `dynamic` type that looks as follows:

```
val dyn: dynamic ="String"
dyn.thisMethodDoesNotExist(1,2,3)
```

No type checks will be run and the code will simply be taken "as is" into the resulting JS files.

> "The most peculiar feature of dynamic is that we are allowed to call any property or function with any parameters on a dynamic variable"

Although the concept makes sense to me, I've been wondering in what situations we would need this feature. Does anyone have concrete examples or use cases?

Kotlin allows us to write **type-safe** JavaScript, which is one of THE reasons to make use of the transpilation thing, right? Why would we give this up and use dynamics then?

Comment: Idea: you could have 2 classes both with a method that has the same signature but not of the same provenience. You could call it this way without having to do any typecasting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's one example usecase for `dynamic` types in the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/javascript/working-with-javascript.html#using-dynamic):

If you want to use e.g. a JQuery **plugin** (e.g. table thingy), which does not provide corresponding *header* [files](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/javascript/working-with-javascript.html#using-ts2kt-to-generate-header-files-for-kotlin), you must call it dynamically because there's no Kotlin equivalent for the library available that could be used for static analysis.

That way, we could call `dataTable()` on our dynamic type although the function is not known at compile time.

Also, sometimes there might be the possibility to program against a compile-safe interface, which is hard to get though. If you then can give up type-safety to get conciseness in return, it might be acceptable to use `dynamic`. Such an example is described in the following post: https://medium.com/@Cypressious/your-second-firefox-extension-in-kotlin-bafd91d87c41

*"Working with external declarations - the static way"* 
**vs.** 
*"Working with external declarations - the dynamic way"*